# interpreting 描き下ろしに描き下ろし

Tags: grammar

> 冬コミ新刊は単行本の描き下ろしに描き下ろし（７０Pくらい) １冊のみになります

a tweet by an artist, how would you read this, or is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little puzzling, but I would read it as "単行本の描き下ろし" AND "描き下ろし(70ページくらい)1冊". The former refers to some new content related to his existing 単行本 (e.g., a small sequel), and the latter refers to a completely new dojinshi with 70 pages.